# why is request.getRemoteAddr() returning square brackets like this: "[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]" instead of just "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1"

Tags: java, ip

This code:

```
   ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
   log.debug("getIP remoteAddr >" +ipAddress + "<");
```

outputs this:

```
 getIP remoteAddr >[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]<
```

Its returning a string of an array!  However its only doing this running java locally.

According to all the java examples in stackoverflow, getRemoteAddr() should return the IP, not an ip in an array!

i have not found an example of code to get the callers ip which removes the square brackets, so this appears to be an anomaly?

Should we look for, and remove "[" and "]" from anything returned by getRemoteAddr to get the desired IP?

Answer (score 1):

Because that's how IPv6 addresses are conventionally represented, and in fact are required to be represented in some contexts.

It's not an array.

The rationale appears when you consider 'address:port' notation.

1:2::3:4  is an IP address

[1:2::3]:4 is an IP address and port

The brackets are also required when an address is used in a URI. What type is your 'request'?  If it is something related to HTTP, there's your answer.

Comment: my understanding is that getRemoteAddr should return the address itself, which I have read should never contain brackets.  brackets are only used in the case the address forms part of a URL, so in conjunction with https:// etc.  In my example, I am getting the remote addr from a servlet called like this https://localhost:4503/xx/yy.  The remote address should simply be "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" or "127.0.0.1"

Comment: What type is 'request'? Given that, perhaps we can read what the documentation tells us about getRemoteAddr().